# Netbeans/Ruby - extraneous(?) autocomplete info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, autocomplete

I'm getting a ton of (what I would call) extraneous autocomplete information in Ruby Netbeans 6.5.1.

For example, if I type the name of a model object and then type a period (whether I'm in a controller or a view), it shows a dizzying dropdown list of thousands of methods, including several hundred different versions of the "new" method (but no documentation - most method signatures are followed by "No comment found").

Has anyone encountered (and solved) this problem, if we agree that this is a problem? Could it be that I simply have access to all of those thousands of methods and so they must be reported by autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same behavior.

I'm guessing because variables in Ruby are dynamically typed, Netbeans is being a little enthusiastic. Coming from a Java background it is a bit surprising.

It does appear to put the columns in my table at the top of my ActiveRecord objects ... so that's nice!

Comment: Yes, it must be the duck typing. Perhaps there's a way to limit the visibility of particular libraries so they don't muddy the namespace.